# Version UIAutomator test package

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-uiautomator

I have a UIAutomator test that interacts with the OS to automate some tasks that I can't do from ADB or another app. Sometimes I release a new version of the tests. I planned on using `adb shell dumpsys package my.package.test | grep versionName` to parse the version from the test app, and update it if necessary.

However, it appears that `dumpsys package` returns `versionName=null` for my UIAutomator test (built using a gradle script near-identical to the [sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/blob/master/ui/uiautomator/BasicSample/app/build.gradle)).

Right now I'm just overwriting the test every time I need it. Is there some way to embed version information in a UIAutomator test APK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no version information in the default manifest generated for the test APK, then you have to introduce it.

## 1.

add this to your `build.gradle`:

```
defaultConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders = [ versionName:versionName, versionCode:versionCode]
}
```

## 2.

copy your main `AndroidManifest.xml` to `src/androidTest`

## 3.

edit the test manifest

```
<!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="your.package.name"
    android:versionCode="${versionCode}"
    android:versionName="${versionName}"
    >
    <application
        tools:node="remove"
        ... >
    </application>
</manifest>
```

## 4.

Once rebuilt, your test APK will include version information.